# Page with absolute DIV tags expand middle bigger with content

Tags: html, css, absolute

I would like to add content (text/picture thumbnails) to an area on the middle of my HTML page. This area currently has "Paragraph of text" repeated throughout. I'd like it so that the DIV tags on the bottom could move down as the one middle DIV expands in size. It would also be nice if the two DIVs along either side of the middle could expand to the same height. Is this possible without manually changing all of the top and left properties?

Currently, I put a scroll bar in the page so that you can view all of the text. I'd like to remove that scroll bar and have the page height expand as necessary when I add content. I know that the absolute positioning is screwing me up, however I adapted this page from other pages on my website that are a set size. I'm sure it's considered bad page design...

Here is the sample page live on my website:
http://envyblade.xoom.it/swtor/sample.html

Update: I removed all of my heights and absolute positioning of all my sub DIVs. I then went and added in box shadowing. I had to resize a few things so it would look similar. This is what I get. It's not as perfect yet: http://envyblade.xoom.it/swtor/sample2.html

The two images wont center between the top and bottom shadow boxes like they did when I was using images. And it would nice to see the bottom box's shadow instead of the page just ending.

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Sample Page</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="sample.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="Mainbox">

    <div class="Slice-07">
        <img src="images/Slice-07.jpg" width="1024" height="25" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="Slice-08">
    </div>
    <div class="Slice-11">
        <h1>Sample Page</h1>    
    </div>
    <div class="Slice-13">
    <p>
        Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text.
    Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text.
    Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. </p>
    <p>
        Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text.
    Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text.
    Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. </p>
    <p>
        Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text.
    Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text.
    Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. </p>
    <p>
        Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text.
    Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text.
    Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. </p>
    <p>
        Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text.
    Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text.
    Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. </p>
    <p>
        Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text.
    Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text.
    Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. </p>
    <p>
        Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text.
    Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text.
    Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. </p>
    <p>
        Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text.
    Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text.
    Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. </p>
    <p>
        Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text.
    Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text.
    Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. </p>
    <p>
        Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text.
    Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text.
    Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. </p>
    <p>
        Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text.
    Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text.
    Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. </p>
    <p>
        Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text.
    Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text.
    Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. </p>
    <p>
        Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text.
    Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text.
    Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. </p>
    <p>
        Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text.
    Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text.
    Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. </p>
    <p>
        Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text.
    Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text.
    Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. </p>
    <p>
        Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text.
    Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text.
    Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. </p>
    <p>
        Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text.
    Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text.
    Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. </p>
    <p>
        Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text.
    Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text.
    Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. </p>
    <p>
        Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text.
    Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text.
    Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. </p>
    <p>
        Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text.
    Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text.
    Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. Paragraph of text. </p>
    </div>
    <div class="Slice-12">
    </div>
    <div class="Slice-23">
        <img src="images/Slice-23.jpg" width="1024" height="32" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="SliceB2">
        <img src="images/logo1.jpg" width="66" height="66" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="SliceB3">Let's do this!
    </div>
    <div class="SliceB4">
        <img src="images/logo2.jpg" width="66" height="66" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="SliceB5">
        <img src="images/SliceB5.jpg" width="1024" height="25" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="SliceB6">
        <img src="images/SliceB6.jpg" width="25" height="140" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="SliceB7">Friendly Links<p>
        <a href="link1.html">Link 1</a> &#8226; <a href="link2.html">Link 2</a> &#8226; 
        <a href="link3.html">Link 3</a><br />
        <a href="link4.html">Link 4</a> &#8226; 
        <a href="link5.html">Link 5</a> &#8226; 
        <a href="link6.html">Link 6</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="SliceB8">Enemy Links<p>
        <a href="link1.html">Link 1</a> &#8226; <a href="link2.html">Link 2</a> &#8226; 
        <a href="link3.html">Link 3</a><br />
        <a href="link4.html">Link 4</a> &#8226; 
        <a href="link5.html">Link 5</a> &#8226; 
        <a href="link6.html">Link 6</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="SliceB9">
        <img src="images/SliceB9.jpg" width="25" height="140" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="SliceB10"><span class="bottomlinks">Website Title: <a href="index.html">Home</a> &#8226; 
        <a href="history.html">History</a> &#8226; <a href="media.html">Video & Photo Memories</a></span>
    </div>
    <div class="SliceB11">
        <img src="images/SliceB11.jpg" width="1024" height="25" alt="">
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

My CSS page:

```
body {
    background-color:#000000;
}

div.Mainbox {
    position:absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -512px;
    top:0px;
    width:1024px;
    height:1024px;
}

div.Slice-07 {
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
    width:1024px;
    height:25px;
}

div.Slice-08 {
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:25px;
    width:34px;
    height:711px;
    background-image:url('images/Slice-08r.jpg');
    background-repeat:repeat-y;
}

div.Slice-11 {
    position:absolute;
    left:34px;
    top:25px;
    width:958px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 90px;
    color:Orange;
    text-shadow: 3px 3px 2px #000000;
    font-family:Comic Sans MS;
}

div.Slice-12 {
    position:absolute;
    left:992px;
    top:25px;
    width:32px;
    height:711px;
    background-image:url('images/Slice-12r.jpg');
    background-repeat:repeat-y;
}

div.Slice-13 {
    position:absolute;
    left:34px;
    top:125px;
    width:958px;
    height:611px;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    overflow-y:scroll;
}

div.Slice-14 {
    position:absolute;
    left:330px;
    top:691px;
    width:23px;
    height:45px;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
}

div.Slice-15 {
    position:absolute;
    left:353px;
    top:691px;
    width:45px;
    height:45px;
}

div.Slice-16 {
    position:absolute;
    left:398px;
    top:691px;
    width:169px;
    height:45px;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    line-height: 45px;
    text-indent: 2px;
}

div.Slice-17 {
    position:absolute;
    left:567px;
    top:691px;
    width:45px;
    height:45px;
}

div.Slice-18 {
    position:absolute;
    left:612px;
    top:691px;
    width:168px;
    height:45px;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    line-height: 45px;
    text-indent: 2px;
}

div.Slice-19 {
    position:absolute;
    left:780px;
    top:691px;
    width:45px;
    height:45px;
}

div.Slice-20 {
    position:absolute;
    left:825px;
    top:691px;
    width:167px;
    height:45px;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    line-height: 45px;
    text-indent: 2px;
}

div.Slice-21 {
    position:absolute;
    left:34px;
    top:715px;
    width:22px;
    height:21px;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
}

div.Slice-22 {
    position:absolute;
    left:56px;
    top:715px;
    width:274px;
    height:21px;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    line-height: 21px;
    text-indent: 2px;
}

div.Slice-23 {
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:736px;
    width:1024px;
    height:32px;
}

div.SliceB2 {
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:768px;
    width:66px;
    height:66px;
}

div.SliceB3 {
    position:absolute;
    left:66px;
    top:768px;
    width:892px;
    height:66px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 66px;
    color:white;
    font-size:26px;
    font-family:Comic Sans MS;
}

div.SliceB4 {
    position:absolute;
    left:958px;
    top:768px;
    width:66px;
    height:66px;
}

div.SliceB5 {
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:834px;
    width:1024px;
    height:25px;
}

div.SliceB6 {
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:859px;
    width:25px;
    height:140px;
}

div.SliceB7 {
    position:absolute;
    left:25px;
    top:859px;
    width:487px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    text-align:center;
}

div.SliceB8 {
    position:absolute;
    left:512px;
    top:859px;
    width:487px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    text-align:center;
}

div.SliceB9 {
    position:absolute;
    left:999px;
    top:859px;
    width:25px;
    height:140px;
}

div.SliceB10 {
    position:absolute;
    left:25px;
    top:959px;
    width:974px;
    height:40px;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 40px;
}

div.SliceB11 {
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:999px;
    width:1024px;
    height:25px;
}

.bottomlinks {
        border-style: dashed;
        border-width: 1px;
        padding: 3px 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem exists in the css rule that is adding a fixed height to the element. Remove all of the fixed heights and your element will expand and force the browser to scroll instead of your element. Once this has been done you will probably need to replace the images with actual CSS box shadows or put the images on repeat. Also a better way to style your page is to get rid of your absolute positioning probably almost every where on website and use margin: auto 0px; to center the element within the page.

Here is a good box shadow generator:

http://www.cssmatic.com/box-shadow

Also Bootstrap might be worth looking into, it is a CSS framework that has a whole online documentation and templates for it.

http://getbootstrap.com/

Comment: Update: I went and removed all heights and added in some float:left. However, I have two issues. I have two small black bars showing up between two of my <div> elements. And secondly, how could I get my side bars to expand downward if those <div> tags no longer have a height?
My new page: http://envyblade.xoom.it/swtor/sample2.html

Comment: Try and limit the usage of images, so therefore remove the side, top and bottom images and replace them with box shadows. You should really look into bootstrap they have some great documentation as well a start up templates.

Comment: Alright. I went and put in box shadows on both the bottom and top of my page. However, I have two problems. I wish to center the two image <div>s outside the phrase "For The Republic!" so it matches up with the text. I was able to mess around with line-height to get "For The Republic!" centered inside of the shadows, but was not able make it work with the images.
Also, is it possible to do any tricks so the bottom shadow on the bottom box can be viewable?

Comment: `.SliceB4 > img, .SliceB2 > img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}`
and 
`div.bottombox {
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}`

Comment: Thank you very much! I can now adapt this to all my pages.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the height attribute from div.Slice-13 and reposition the elements below it;

Comment: My problem is that div.Slice-13 will get updates and grow in size, so I dont want to have to update the positioning of the <div>s below it. Is there a way to position divs relative to the div above it?

Comment: position: relative; (which is default)